# How to use Navlink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i use Navlink to navigate new path but for example :
my path is "/home" when i click to "/news" link my path changed to "/home/news"
i want this path "/news/
i use Navlink "react-router-dom"

```
 <NavLink
                  key={getKeyEleman()}
                  className="navMenuItem"
                  style={{ color: item.color || "var(--warmGrey)" }}
                  onClick={() => setOpenNavMenu(false)}
                  to={item.route}
                >
```

Comment: What does item.route equals?

Comment: items = [
  {
    ...
    route: "/home",
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    route: "/news",
    ...
  },
  ...
];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are clicking the link and it's appending the `item.route` to the current path then it sounds like you are using *relative* routing instead of absolute routing. Ensure your link target path has a leading `"/"` character.

```
to={`/${item.route}`}
```

Or fix the data you are mapping so it has the absolute path.

```
items = [
  {
    ...
    route: "/home",
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    route: "/news",
    ...
  },
  ...
];
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-navlink]

Comment: yes i’m sure my path has a “/“

Comment: @MohammadrezaAtaei Can you provide us a reproducible example? A *running* codesandbox would be great for this, we could inspect & debug it live to see exactly what the code is rendering and doing.

Comment: unfortunantly no but i can explain to you

Comment: You can't create a minimal, reproducible demo for us? It doesn't need to be any private/protected code, just code that reproduces the issue, the goal being if we can resolve the issue you can apply solution to your real code. Can you at least provide us a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It nearly impossible to debug code we can't see.

Comment: I have a NavBar Component with some text to navigate this page and in that page i imported Navbar component for example i’m in newsPage with path “/news” and i open navbar an click on contactus page with path “/contactus” my route chenged to “/news/contactus” i want to navigate contactus page with route “/contactus”

Comment: @MohammadrezaAtaei Here's a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-navlink-su009z) with working links. Could you try forking this one and adding in more of your app's code until the navigation issue is reproduced?